# How to start a background process from Org?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

The following code waits until process is finished, which is unexpected

```
#+begin_src shell
perl -wE 'sleep(3)' & disown 
#+end_src
```

The work-around for that is to close `STDIN` and `STDOUT` explicitly

```
#+begin_src shell
perl -wE 'STDIN->close(); STDOUT->close(); sleep(3)' & disown 
#+end_src
```

But what should I do if it's impossible to change the code inside src block?
I.e

```
#+begin_src shell
./readonly-deamon-script start # has & and disown inside
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can close the file descriptors for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` using a `:prologue` header arg. Of course, if the script opens other file descriptors, you will have to close those too, but in the simplest case, the three standard ones will be enough:

```
#+begin_src shell :prologue exec 0>&- 1>&- 2>&-
sleep 10 & disown
#+end_src
```

Comment: What does Emacs want these file descriptors closed?

Comment: Emacs does not really care but Org Babel is trying to collect the output so that it can present you with the result.